# Finding Matrix Representations of a Dicyclic Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Consider the dicyclic group with 16 elements,
$$
Dic_4 = \langle a,b \mid a^8 = 1, b^2 = a^4, b^{-1} a b = a^{-1} \rangle.
$$

There are two faithful irreps of this group, say $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$. The character table for these is given by
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline 
 & a^0 & a^{\pm 1} & a^{\pm 2} & a^{\pm 3} & a^4 & a^\text{even} b & a^\text{odd} b \\ \hline 
\delta_1 & 2 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & -\sqrt{2} & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
\delta_2 & 2 & -\sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} & -2 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline 
\end{array}
$$

The irrep $\delta_1$ is the fundamental one and a matrix representation is $a = S$ and $b = X$ where
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ -i & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad S =  \begin{pmatrix} \zeta_8^* & 0 \\ 0 & \zeta_8 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and $\zeta_8 = e^{i \pi/4}$ is an $8$-th root of unity.

On the other hand, $\delta_2$ is the conjugate irrep and we get the characters via the Galois conjugate - replacing each $\zeta_8$ by $\zeta_8^3$. For example, $a$ for $\delta_1$ has character $\sqrt{2} = \zeta_8 + \zeta_8^*$ and so $a$ for $\delta_3$ has character $\zeta_8^3 + \zeta_8^{3*} = -\sqrt{2}$.

My question is about how to actually find "the" matrix representation for $\delta_2$? It seems like we can cheat off of the Galois conjugate and just replace each $\zeta_8$ with $\zeta_8^3$, i.e., take $a = S^3$ and $b = X$. However, we could also make the replacement $\zeta_8 \to \zeta_8^3$ but also take the conjugate of the matrix, i.e., $a = S^{3*}$ and $b = X$.

Both seem to be valid irreps so my question is basically which representation of $\delta_2$ is "more correct"? Or maybe both are "equally correct" and the question becomes how many different choices of irreps given the representation of $\delta_1$ are there?

Obviously this question can be easily generalized to say $Dic_{2^r}$ in which case there are $2^{r-1}$ faithful irreps and the $S$ matrix above gets replaced by a diagonal matrix with entries $\zeta_{2^{r+1}}^*$ and $\zeta_{2^{r+1}}$. My question is basically how do you generically find the other faithful matrix representations given a representation of the fundamental irrep?

Comment: When we say there are two irreducible representations of a group we mean that there are two equivalence classes. Each equivalence class contains infinitely many different representations, and none of them are a priori more correct than any of the others. In practice of course you might prefer to choose a representative representation in which the matrix entries are not too complicated to write down, with perhaps as many zero entries as possible.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yeah I figured as much. I was hoping that given a representation of the fundamental irrep would maybe "fix" the other irreps.